# hadoop: port appears open locally but not remotelly

Tags: linux, linux-networking, hadoop

I am new to linux and hadoop and I am having the same issue as in [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/393741/port-appears-open-locally-but-closed-from-another-machine) question. I think I understand what is causing it but  I don't know how to solve it (Don't know what they mean by "Edit the Hadoop server's configuration file so that it includes its NIC's address."). The other post that they link says that the configuration files should refer to the machine's externally accessible host name. I think I got this right as every hadoop configuration file refers to "master" and the etc/hosts file lists the master by its private IP address. How can I solve this?

Edit: I have 5 nodes: `master`, `slavec`, `slaved`, `slavee` and `slavef` all running debian. This is the hosts file in `master`:

```
127.0.0.1       master
10.0.1.201      slavec
10.0.1.202      slaved
10.0.1.203      slavee
10.0.1.204      slavef
```

this is the hosts file in `slavec` (it looks similar in the other slaves):

```
10.0.1.200      master
127.0.0.1       slavec
10.0.1.202      slaved
10.0.1.203      slavee
10.0.1.204      slavef
```

the masters file in `master`:

```
master
```

the slaves file in `master`:

```
master
slavec
slaved
slavee
slavef
```

the masters and slaves file in `slavex` has only one line: `slavex`

Comment: Are you able to describe your cluster setup (nodes, network config etc) in more detail? Possibly post your masters and slaves files?

Comment: Have you already seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855808/hadoop-job-tracker-only-accessible-from-localhost) ?

Comment: @Alex Yes, I have. That's what I meant by "The other post that they link ..." but I am not sure I got it right.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is a great tutorial to start on Hadoop:
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/

Second, analyzing your environment, seems that /etc/hosts, "master" and "slave" files are misconfigured. You could setup one "hosts" file and share to all nodes. From your scenario, it should be like this:

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
10.0.1.200      master
10.0.1.201      slavec
10.0.1.202      slaved
10.0.1.203      slavee
10.0.1.204      slavef
```

Third, "master" and "slaves" files should be configured **only** on the "master" node. The first file has only the server that will run JobTracker and NameNode, the second file has all servers that will run TaskTracker and DataNode.